# Adjacency Matrix for an Undirected Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Here is an undirected graph

```
  m = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 8}, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

We can get the Adjacency Matrix as follows

```
g = AdjacencyMatrix[m]
```

The Normal Form of the sparse array g is as follows.

```
In[28]:= Normal[g]

Out[28]= {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

The adjacency matrix does not appear to be correct for the graph m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ordering of the vertices used for `AdjacencyMatrix` is that given in `VertexList[m]`:

```
ordering={1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

Thus, while it looks like the adjacency matrix is saying that 1 and 2 are joined. If you look at the ordering in `VertexList` You'll see that the second element is actually node number 3.